# combining two dictionaries additively on the values

Tags: python

I have two JSON files which I want to combine. An an example, I have:

file1

```
{
    "counts":
    {
        "chemical_1": [100, 15.1],
        "chemical_2": [19.5]
    }
}
```

file2

```
{
    "counts":
    {
        "chemical_3": [100, 15.1],
        "chemical_4": [19.5]
    }
}
```

Now I want to combine it so that there is one file with:

```
{
    "counts":
    {
       "chemical_1": [100, 15.1],
       "chemical_2": [19.5],
       "chemical_3": [100, 15.1],
       "chemical_4": [19.5]
    }
}
```

So I tried something like:

```
with open('2.json') as f:
    y = json.load(f)

with open('1.json') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

merged = list(x.items()) + list(y.items())
```

This returns something like:

```
[('counts', {'chemical_1': [100, 15.1], 'chemical_2': [19.5]}),
 ('counts', {'chemical_3': [100, 15.1], 'chemical_4': [19.5]})]
```

How is it possible to get it to combine the values from the dictionary in an additive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very interesting.As we know, the json can be loaded as dict in python.And we found the two json have common key.

```
json one:
{
    "counts":
    {
        "chemical_1": [100, 15.1],
        "chemical_2": [19.5]
    }
}
json two:
{
    "counts":
    {
        "chemical_3": [100, 15.1],
        "chemical_4": [19.5]
    }
}
```

So we load two json in python.

```
with open('1.json') as f:
    dict1 = json.load(f)
with open('2.json') as f:
    dict2 = json.load(f)
```

Now our job is merge the value.

```
for k, v in dict2.items():
    if k in dict1.keys():
        dict1[k].update(v)
```

The output:

```
>>> dict1
{
    'counts': 
        {'chemical_1': [100, 15.1], 
         'chemical_2': [19.5], 
         'chemical_3': [100, 15.1], 
         'chemical_4': [19.5]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine the `count` values of each, not the whole object. For that access the mappings name/values with `x['count']` and unpack it with the other one in a new dict, on a new `count` key

```
merged = {'count': {**x['count'], **y['count']}}
```

You could also do

```
x['count'].update(y['count'])
# x is like merged in the other example
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `update` method as follows:

```
with open('2.json') as f:
    y = json.load(f)

with open('1.json') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

y["counts"].update(x["counts"])
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
with open('2.json') as f:
    y = json.load(f)

with open('1.json') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

x['counts'].update(y['counts'])
# OR
x3 = dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))
```

Comment: yeah, I fixed and added an option to create a new variable